# Unable to download artifact from TeamCity using REST API

Tags: rest, continuous-integration, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I have having trouble download artifacts from TeamCity. On [TeamCity's confluence page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts#PatternsForAccessingBuildArtifacts-ObtainingArtifacts) it says to use

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastFinished/ARTIFACT_PATH
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastSuccessful/ARTIFACT_PATH
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastPinned/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

to download the artifacts. However I would always get a 404 page not found. For example, if I look at the url bar for the artifact that I wish to download on TeamCity

```
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/viewLog.html?buildId=12345&buildTypeId=MyProjectName&tab=artifacts
```

And then I fill out the REST API call according to that confluence page

```
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/repository/download/MyProjectName/.lastSuccessful/12345
```

I would always get a 404 Page Not Found. And just for sanity check I have also tried

```
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/httpAuth/repository/download/MyProjectName/.lastFinished/artifact_folder.zip
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/httpAuth/repository/download/MyProjectName/.lastFinished/artifact_folder
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/httpAuth/repository/download/MyProjectName/.lastFinished/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:1234/artifacts/children/artifact_folder/v0.1.3
```

but none them it works.

When I shorten the url to

```
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/repository/download/MyProjectName
```

I can see a page of url links, however when I click on any of them I would get a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, This site can’t be reached`

I am currently using [How do you programatically download the artifacts from the latest Team City build using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664603/how-do-you-programatically-download-the-artifacts-from-the-latest-team-city-buil)
 to download the artifacts, but I feel like the official documented way should work.

So how do I make `/repository/download/` work?

Answer (score 0):

ARTIFACT_PATH is a path to a file and not to a folder.
So the correct URL will be:
https://teamcity.MyServer.com/httpAuth/repository/download/MyProjectName/.lastFinished/ARTIFACT_PATH

For example, if on Artifacts tab you see the following structure "t100/generic/test.log", then ARTIFACT_PATH is t100/generic/test.log